# Use list of integers as argument for fill function

Tags: scala

I have `L = Seq[Int]` and I want to use it in this expression somehow

```
Seq.fill[T]( L )(new T)
```

In place of L I can put integers one by one like this `Seq.fill[T]( 5, 3, 8 )(new T)` , but I want to put them all at once. What is the best way to do it? (if possible)

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin I want a multidimensional array, of unknown dimension (from 2 to 10 f.e.)

Comment: If the dimensions are known only at runtime how will you index it to retrieve values? The compiler won't allow `mySeq(1)(1)(1)` because the compiler won't know if it is a 2, 3, or 5 dimensional `Seq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `Seq.fill` is an overloaded method. When you call it, the compiler has to pick the correct overload at compile time. While a `Seq[Int]` can hold anything from 0 to 2147483647 ints. You can't know at compile time how many ints will be in the `Seq[Int]`, so you can't know which overload, if any, you have to select.

Comment: ok, so is there a way to create multidimensional array of unknown dimension (from 2 to 10 f.e.) ? And fill it also... Thanks

Comment: How would you plan on using that array later on when you don't know its dimensions?

Comment: I will know it at the time of using it, in the running part I will have it. Should I make 10 different versions of the class in according to the wanted dimension?